Is $H^1(G_{\Bbb{Q}_p},E[2])=0$ for good prime of $E/\Bbb{Q}$?
Let $E/\Bbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve over number field $\Bbb{Q}$. Let $p$ be a prime number.
$H^1(G_{\Bbb{Q}_p},E)$ is $0$ for good prime of $E/\Bbb{Q}$ because every genus $1$ curve over $\Bbb{F}_p$ has a rational point.
My question is,

is $H^1(G_{\Bbb{Q}_p},E[2])=0$ for good prime of $E/\Bbb{Q}$?

There is surjection $H^1(G_{\Bbb{Q}_p},E[2])\to H^1(G_{\Bbb{Q}_p},E)[2]$, and there is no apriori reason for me that this is true.

No - I don't think this is ever true.
For an easy example, take any prime $p$ that splits completely in $\mathbb Q(E[2]))$. Then $H^1(G_{\mathbb Q_p}, E[2]) \cong H^1(G_{\mathbb Q_p}, \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z) = \mathrm{Hom}(G_{\mathbb Q_p}, (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^2)$. There are plenty of non-trivial extensions of $G_{\mathbb Q_p}$ with Galois group contained in $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^2$.
More generally, write $E\colon y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$, and let $K = \mathbb Q_p[x]/(x^3 + ax + b)$. Then there is an isomorphism
$$H^1(G_{\mathbb Q_p}, E[2])\cong \ker(K^\times/K^{\times 2}\xrightarrow{\mathrm{Nm}}\mathbb{Q}_p^\times/\mathbb Q_p^{\times 2}),$$
which you can calculate explcitly depending on the splitting of $p$.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This amounts more or less to what you wrote, but it’s worth noting that the cardinality of $H^1(G_{\mathbb{Q}_p},E[2])$ is exactly the squre of the cardinality of $E(\mathbb{Q}_p)[2]$.
